# C : Store PID in global variable

Tags: c, process, operating-system, global-variables, fork

I am currently working on a school project and I wanted to store the PID of my process in the global array id, so that I can use it in another function :

```
int id[3];

int main(int agrc,const char* agrv[]) {
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if((fork() == 0)) {
        id[i] = (int)getpid();
        printf("ID[%d] = %d\n",i,id[i]);
        if(i != 3) {
            printf("I am a wharehouse. PID = [%d] PPID = [%d]\n",getpid(),getppid());
            whcode();
            exit(0);
        }
        else if(i == 3) {
            printf("I am the central. PID = [%d] PPID = [%d]\n",getpid(),getppid());
            central_code();
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}
sleep(2);

printf("ID[0] = %d\n",id[0]);
printf("ID[1] = %d\n",id[1]);
printf("ID[2] = %d\n",id[2]);

}
```

But when I run this the output of the last 3 prints is 0, where it should be the PID of each process. Why does this happen?

Comment: Try `int id[3] = { -2, -3, -4 };` and post the output.

Comment: that's cause every child process that sets the id variable, exits before those last 3 prints.

Comment: regarding: `int main(int agrc,const char* agrv[])`  when the parameters to `main()` are not going to be used, then the signature ; `int main( void )` should be used.  Otherwise the compiler will output 2 warnings about unused function parameters

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  2) separate code blocks `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Amongst other things, it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files.  Do you expect us to guess as to which header files your code actually includes?  Please post a [mcve] when asking about a run time problem.

Comment: using the call to `sleep()` is not a guaranteed way to wait for the child processes to exit.   Much better to call `wait()` or `waitpid()` for each child process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the call to `fork()`, new process is created with separate virtual memory space. This child process will return from the call to fork with `0`, so in your code, this child will go inside the if branch and assign to `id[i]` it's pid. But this assignment is happening in a separate process, with separate virtual memory, so it has no effect on the parents virtual memory space and the parent will not see any change in its array. That is why your code prints the zeroes.

If you want to print the pids of the children by the parent, use the return value of fork(), which in parent is the pid of the child process. Inside the for, use code such as this:

```
pid_t child_id;
switch (child_id = fork()) {
    case -1:
        //Fork failed, exit with error or something
        break;
    case 0:
        //Child code
        printf("ID[%d] = %d\n",i,id[i]);
        if(i != 3) {
            printf("I am a wharehouse. PID = [%d] PPID = [%d]\n",getpid(),getppid());
            whcode();
            exit(0);
        }
        else if(i == 3) {
            printf("I am the central. PID = [%d] PPID = [%d]\n",getpid(),getppid());
            central_code();
            exit(0);
        }
        break;
    default:
       id[i] = child_id;
       break;
}
```

By the way, you should really declare the id array as `pid_t id[3]`, and when printing, print it as long. That for now is probably the most portable way to handle these things.

Comment: "print it as long" is simply a guess as to `pid_t` type and can fail when `pid_t` is an `int` . Print to a casted wide type like  `printf("%ld\n", (long)getpid());`, `printf("%jd\n", (intmax_t)getpid());`.

Comment: Yeah that is what i wanted to say, to cast it to long, longlong or if there is a type alias for the biggest integer type possible and then print it. It was two in the morning so i cut it little short :D. Thank you for the correction.